# Building Adversarial auto encoder using VAE and discriminator

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I have been working on Celeb dataset and trying to build an AAE network using variational auto encoders and discriminator. I have created all the required models and discriminator but I am facing some issue while training process of the network. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is my discriminator model

```
# Discriminator model
discriminator_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='discriminator_input')
x = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(discriminator_input)
x = Dense(32)(x)
discriminator_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='discriminator_output')(x)

discriminator_model = Model(discriminator_input, discriminator_output, name='discriminator_model')
discriminator_model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
discriminator_model.summary()
```

Below is my AAE model

```
aae_output = discriminator_model(encoder_model(encoder_input))
aae = Model(inputs=encoder_input, outputs=[vae(encoder_input), aae_output])
aae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss={'vae': 'CustomLayer()', 'discriminator_model': binary_crossentropy})
aae.summary()
```

My training loop looks something like this:

```
epochs = 10
batch_size =32 
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

# valid = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
# fake = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))

for epoch in range(epochs):

    print("Starting vae loss")
    # Train the VAE
    vae_loss=vae.fit(training_data, None, epochs = 1, batch_size = 32)

    print("Starting generated_samples")
    # Generate fake samples using the VAE
    generated_samples = vae.predict(training_data)

    # Create labels for real and generated samples
    print("Starting real and fake labels")
    real_labels = np.ones((len(training_data), 1))
    fake_labels = np.zeros((len(training_data), 1))

    print(real_labels.shape)
    print(fake_labels.shape)
    print(generated_samples.shape)

    print("Starting discriminator loss")
    # Train the discriminator with real and generated samples
    # discriminator_loss = discriminator_model.fit(generated_samples,fake_labels)

    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, latent_dim))
    d_loss_real = discriminator_model.train_on_batch(encoder_model.predict(training_data), real_labels)
    d_loss_fake = discriminator_model.train_on_batch(noise, fake_labels)
    d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake)

    # Train the adversarial_autoencoder
    g_loss = aae.train_on_batch(training_data, {'vae': real_labels, 'discriminator_model': real_labels})

    # Print or log the losses for monitoring
    # print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs}, VAE Loss: {vae_loss["vae"]}, Discriminator Loss: {discriminator_loss}')

    print("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f, mse: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100 * d_loss[1], g_loss[0], g_loss[1]))
```

I have my training data in the variable "training_data". There is no separate x and y labels for my data.

So my issue is that at d_loss_real I am getting error saying:

Layer "discriminator_model" expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors

or sometimes the kernel crashes even having enough space for processing.

I have tried multiple things here, but nothing is working out. I am pretty sure the mistake is not very big but I have not figured it out yet.